# How to make datagridview row height auto adjust/wrap dynamically with a horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

UI:

[image]

Btn click code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column 1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column 2");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column 3");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column 4");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column 5");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Column 1"] = "Col1 Test";
            dr["Column 2"] = "Col2 Test";
            dr["Column 3"] = "Col3 Test";
            dr["Column 4"] = "Col4 Test";
            dr["Column 5"] = "Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test Col5 Test ";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column 5"].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
            dataGridView1.Columns["Column 5"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        }
```

Result:

[image]

If I reduce the size of gridview, via the visual studio designer and relaunch the app, then the horizontal bar doesn't show up.

UI:

[image]

Output:

[image]

How to make datagridview row and column wrap and autosize such that it doesn't cramp up in the space? I want it to dynamically adjust the row height and automatically show the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are describing?

Comment: Just a normal datagridview, I have pasted the code above.

Comment: In my tests using the posted code, if the column(s) resize such that the columns go beyond the size of the grid, then the horizontal scroll bar shows as expected. Can you post a [mre] that demonstrates this?

Comment: Are you making any other settings to the datagridview other than default settings?

Comment: No. I created a `DataTable` added a couple of columns and set it as a `DataSource` to the grid. Then executed your posted code. Granted “while” typing into the “auto size” column, the column will not expand until the user presses the enter key or leaves the cell. I can only guess this may be what you are describing.

Comment: No I have a readonly datagridview. The data source property is assigned to a datatable.

Comment: Setting the grid to read only made no difference, the horizontal bar displays as expected. I can only guess something else is going on that you are not revealing.

Comment: Try not to autosize just the displayed Cells.

Comment: Is there any guidance example on how to configure this?

Comment: I am not following your last comment… _”Is there any guidance example on how to configure this?”_ … to configure “what”? … You make a claim that the code does not show the horizontal scrollbar when the column widths become greater than the grids width. Yet, you show NO example of this. The posted code does indeed show a horizontal scroll bar… despite your claim. So we can only assume something else is going on. As I previously commented, creating a [mre] that DID show that the horizontal bar does not display would validate your claim.

Comment: I can only assume that you either do not want to make an MRE that validates your claim… OR you CAN’T make an MRE that demonstrates your claim. Please do yourself a favor and everyone else and make an MRE and post it. Otherwise, you will end up with a bunch of useless back and forth questions that are unnecessary and get you no closer to an answer. Please post some code that demonstrates your claim.

Comment: I have added details and examples to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are wanting to achieve or HOW the grid is sized to begin with. Is the user able to “resize” the grid or columns? Is the goal to set the grid’s width (up to a certain size) to show all the columns? In other words, what is the overall goal in relation to the grid and the columns in it.

In a short answer… The issue you are having is because the `DataGridView` is just not very smart. In addition to add confusion to the picture, but does not apply here, is that there are two (2) `AutoSizeColumnMode` settings… let me try to explain…

For starters, there are two (2) different “AutoSizeMode” properties that can be used to auto size columns in a grid and this may cause some confusion. One is for the WHOLE GRID… the `AutoSizeColumnMode` which applies to the grid… and there is another property for the individual columns… `AutoSizeMode`.

I am confident that whatever the GRID’S `AutoSizeColumnMode` is set to will OVERRIDE any individual column setting if there is a conflict. Example IF the GRID’S `AutoSizeColumnMode` is set to `Fill`… THEN, IF… you set an individual column’s `AutoSizeMode` to something other than `Fill`… THEN… the GRID’S `Fill` setting will be used.

In most cases I have found that setting the GRIDS auto size mode to `NONE` and manually set the individual columns auto size mode is at least predictable and consistent.

Another issue is that the grid is not very smart and will obligingly stuff 100’s of columns of data into a grid that is not wide enough to hold all the columns. The minimum size of each column would be set to something like 5 pixels. Obviously this is not useful since you cannot see the data, but the grid will obligingly do this this if the setting is set to “Fill” and there are too many columns and/or the grid's width is not wide enough. This is similar to what you see in the last picture with column 5.

In this particular situation with your posted code…

The reason the last picture does NOT show a horizontal scroll bar is because the last column’s (Column 5) `AutoSizeMode` is set to `Fill`… AND… the GRIDS WIDTH is wide enough such that, column 5 still has room to “FILL” the grids width. This is why you see the vertical scroll bar but no horizontal scroll bar, since the column still “FITS” in the grid…

IF… you make the GRIDS WIDTH less than the width of the first four (4) columns, THEN, the horizontal scroll bar will display, HOWEVER, if you scroll to the right to see column 5…. column 5 will have a width of something like 5 pixels which obviously is of no use since we would not be able to see any of the data.

I hope the above info helps and given what you describe I am guessing what you are looking for is to NOT set columns 5’s `AutoSizeMode` to `Fill`… is what you want is to set column 5’s `AutoSizeMode` to `AllCells`.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Column 5"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

This will produce something like shown below.

[image]

Bear in mind, that IF the grid is wide enough and column 5’s width is such that it leaves a gap at the end, THEN you will need to look for this in your code. Example you would know that if the grids width is greater than some value, then yes, you want to set column 5’s auto size mode  to `Fill`, if it is less than a certain value then you want to set it to `AllCells`.

Unfortunately, as I previously commented, the grid is not very smart and if you want the columns to display in a particular manner, then it may be necessary create a method to examine the columns and determine what setting to give each column. I have done this in the past and it is not that difficult to get around the grid’s shortcomings.

Comment: Making the change you have suggested results in gridview taking long time to load

Comment: Hmm…. The title to your question is… _”How to make datagridview row height auto adjust/wrap dynamically with a horizontal scroll bar?”_ … ? …. I felt my answer at least explained “why” the horizontal scroll did not show…….  Now… from your comment… my solution… _”results in gridview taking long time to load”_ …?  … I guess I am not understanding your question. Sorry if I missed something. Good luck